# Unable to create a dynamic component using viewContainerRef.createComponent

Tags: angular

I'm following the angular dynamic component loader tutorial, https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader, and tried to make something very simple myself, which is following the same steps as the tutorial. But for some reason, my component does not show up.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mqikxl?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Comment: You misspelled the `OnInit` function. It is `ngOnInit`

Comment: Ah.. the classic. For me at least. Thanks